# Java: how to intercept video and audio streams?

Tags: java, flash, browser, video-streaming, video-capture

is there any Java library out there that can help intercept video and audio streams being sent through the browser?

So for example, a video starts loading through a flash player using some Flash server, the java application would listen for video/audio stream and capture and write it to video on the disk.

Comment: *write it to a file on disk ;)

Comment: Why Java? The technology for capturing network things is more likely to be available from C, not Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe its to late, but scince google got me here I will answer this.

If you want to "Intercept" the data streams, the closer you can get to this is charlesproxy:
http://www.charlesproxy.com/download/

which is a HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor / Reverse Proxy that enables a developer to view all of the HTTP and SSL / HTTPS traffic between their machine and the Internet.

You will have to play around with your browser configuration but it should do the trick.

its an aproach, dont know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any Java library out there that can help intercept video and audio streams being sent through the browser?

The simple answer is no.

There is probably not a library to do it in *any* language.  (No operating system I've ever heard of allows one process to snoop on the socket-level data streams of another process.)

In theory you could do this with a network traffic analyser (e.g. wireshark) but the chances are that you'd miss stuff and the result would be a corrupted video / audio stream.

The only approach that I think would have a chance of working reliably would be to modify the browser and/or the plugins to capture the data streams.

Comment: what about a firefox plugin/add on that can do this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any firefox plugin/addon that can do this.  In fact I don't think that that approach could possibly work.  (It would involve one plugin snooping on the streams owned by another plugin.  That would have really nasty security implications ... and I can't imagine the Firefox developers thinking it would be a good idea.)

Comment: @stephen C - there is flash got, it can get most streams from flash players

Comment: @epoch - I don't think that is **intercepting** streams.  Rather it is downloading them as a separate objects after having dug their location URLs out of the flash player object.